# React algirthm - recursive prepend and append

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

I have the following two variables as premise:

```
const snippets = [
{ start: 48.12, end: 50.8, id: 12, snippetTitle: "This is the title" },
{ start: 48.29, end: 49.1, id: 13, snippetTitle: "This is the title" }
];

let words = [{"word":" yeah","start_time":"46.44","end_time":"46.82","__typename":"SimplifiedWord"},{"word":".","start_time":"46.44","end_time":"46.82","__typename":"SimplifiedWord"},{"word":" So","start_time":"47.55","end_time":"47.81","__typename":"SimplifiedWord"},{"word":" now","start_time":"47.82","end_time":"48.12","__typename":"SimplifiedWord"},{"word":" it","start_time":"48.12","end_time":"48.28","__typename":"SimplifiedWord"},{"word":" works","start_time":"48.29","end_time":"48.74","__typename":"SimplifiedWord"},{"word":" for","start_time":"48.75","end_time":"49.1","__typename":"SimplifiedWord"},{"word":" for","start_time":"49.11","end_time":"49.67","__typename":"SimplifiedWord"},{"word":" to","start_time":"49.68","end_time":"50.23","__typename":"SimplifiedWord"},{"word":" let","start_time":"50.33","end_time":"50.62","__typename":"SimplifiedWord"},{"word":" me","start_time":"50.62","end_time":"50.8","__typename":"SimplifiedWord"},{"word":" refresh","start_time":"50.8","end_time":"51.41","__typename":"SimplifiedWord"},{"word":" the","start_time":"51.42","end_time":"51.72","__typename":"SimplifiedWord"},{"word":" computer","start_time":"51.73","end_time":"52.55","__typename":"SimplifiedWord"},{"word":".","start_time":"51.73","end_time":"52.55","__typename":"SimplifiedWord"}];
```

I am trying to find all combinations of series I can make by this data. Basically I want to show where a user has made some snippets base on `start` and `end`  but these snippets can overlap. What I mean by that is take the sample one in snippets variable: before the start of the word at 48.12 start_time, i want to start adding those between 48.12 and 50.8 to an array. But in this interval another snippet can occur, like between 48.29 and 49.1, that would be a snippet inside a snippet. How can I make it dynamic and recursive to wrap all those elements in an array inside a parent element but still have the possibility to overlap.

I tried something like this:

```
let x = words.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, idx) => {
        let isin = isInSnippets(currentValue);
        if (!isin) {
            if (cache.length > 0) {
                accumulator.push(
                    <Snippet className="wrapit" key={idx}>
                        <TextContent
                            words={cache}
                            skip
                            identity={identity}
                        ></TextContent>
                    </Snippet>
                );
                cache = [];
            }
            accumulator.push(
                <span
                    key={`${currentValue.word}${idx}`}
                    data-start={currentValue.start_time}
                    data-end={currentValue.end_time}
                    data-idnt={identity}
                >
                    {currentValue.word}
                </span>
            );
        } else cache.push(currentValue);
        return accumulator;
    }, []);
```

but this approach does not seem to handle nested cases. It works ok for a single snippet, or if a small snippet is contained in a bigger one, just the big one is wrapped in Snippet component.

Basically i want to have the final result something like this:

```
    <span data-start="46.44" data-end="46.82"> yeah</span>
    <span data-start="46.44" data-end="46.82">.</span>
    <span data-start="47.55" data-end="47.81"> So</span>
    <span data-start="47.82" data-end="48.12"> now</span>
    <Snippet>
    <span data-start="48.12" data-end="48.28"> it</span>
    <Snippet>
    <span data-start="48.29" data-end="48.74"> works</span>
    <span data-start="48.75" data-end="49.1"> for</span>
    </Snippet>
    <span data-start="49.11" data-end="49.67"> for</span>
    <span data-start="49.68" data-end="50.23"> to</span>
    <span data-start="50.33" data-end="50.62"> let</span>
    <span data-start="50.62" data-end="50.8"> me</span>
    </Snippet>
    <span data-start="50.8" data-end="51.41"> refresh</span>
    <span data-start="51.42" data-end="51.72"> the</span>
    <span data-start="51.73" data-end="52.55"> computer</span>
    <span data-start="51.73" data-end="52.55">.</span>
</div>
```

Notice the Snippet inside the Snippet in the final result.

Comment: Could you please post the expected answer like the code posted for question. And anything you tried for solving the problem.

Comment: added the code i've tried for now and the end result i want.

Comment: please post your solution if there any simpler alternative to the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I don'think you really need `recursion` here.

If you have the ranges in **sequence**, then the below code should work.

```js
const words = [{
  "word": " yeah",
  "start_time": "46.44",
  "end_time": "46.82",
  "__typename": "SimplifiedWord"
}, {
  "word": ".",
  "start_time": "46.44",
  "end_time": "46.82",
  "__typename": "SimplifiedWord"
}, {
  "word": " So",
  "start_time": "47.55",
  "end_time": "47.81",
  "__typename": "SimplifiedWord"
}, {
  "word": " now",
  "start_time": "47.82",
  "end_time": "48.12",
  "__typename": "SimplifiedWord"
}, {
  "word": " it",
  "start_time": "48.12",
  "end_time": "48.28",
  "__typename": "SimplifiedWord"
}, {
  "word": " works",
  "start_time": "48.29",
  "end_time": "48.74",
  "__typename": "SimplifiedWord"
}, {
  "word": " for",
  "start_time": "48.75",
  "end_time": "49.1",
  "__typename": "SimplifiedWord"
}, {
  "word": " for",
  "start_time": "49.11",
  "end_time": "49.67",
  "__typename": "SimplifiedWord"
}, {
  "word": " to",
  "start_time": "49.68",
  "end_time": "50.23",
  "__typename": "SimplifiedWord"
}, {
  "word": " let",
  "start_time": "50.33",
  "end_time": "50.62",
  "__typename": "SimplifiedWord"
}, {
  "word": " me",
  "start_time": "50.62",
  "end_time": "50.8",
  "__typename": "SimplifiedWord"
}, {
  "word": " refresh",
  "start_time": "50.8",
  "end_time": "51.41",
  "__typename": "SimplifiedWord"
}, {
  "word": " the",
  "start_time": "51.42",
  "end_time": "51.72",
  "__typename": "SimplifiedWord"
}, {
  "word": " computer",
  "start_time": "51.73",
  "end_time": "52.55",
  "__typename": "SimplifiedWord"
}, {
  "word": ".",
  "start_time": "51.73",
  "end_time": "52.55",
  "__typename": "SimplifiedWord"
}];

const snippets = [{
    start: 48.12,
    end: 50.8,
    id: 12,
    snippetTitle: "This is the title"
  },
  {
    start: 48.29,
    end: 49.1,
    id: 13,
    snippetTitle: "This is the title"
  }
];

const [outerRange, innerRange] = snippets.map(item => ({
  start: item.start,
  end: item.end
}));
// console.log({outerRange, innerRange});

const output = [];
let innerSnippetSets = "";
let outerSnippetSets = "";

words.forEach(item => {
  const start = Number(item.start_time);
  const end = Number(item.end_time);
  if (start >= outerRange.start && end <= outerRange.end) {
    if (start >= innerRange.start && end <= innerRange.end) {
      innerSnippetSets += `   <span data-start="${start}" data-end="${end}">${item.word}</span>` + "\n";
    } else {
      if (innerSnippetSets) {
        outerSnippetSets += "<Sinppet>\n" + innerSnippetSets + "</Snippet>" + "\n";
        innerSnippetSets = "";
      }
      outerSnippetSets += `   <span data-start="${start}" data-end="${end}">${item.word}</span>` + "\n";;
    }
  } else {
    if (outerSnippetSets) {
      output.push("<Sinppet>\n" + outerSnippetSets + "</Snippet>");
      outerSnippetSets = "";
    }
    output.push(`<span data-start="${start}" data-end="${end}">${item.word}</span>`);
  }
});


output.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

Comment: the problem with this is that it works with only two snippets, but i can have 1 to N snippets.

Comment: I still believe O(n) solution like above should work. Little modification to above answer(like wrapping whole thing about inside a function and reusing it) might solve the issue. Could you please update the input data as such...?